# Strange black bars in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm really scratching my head over this one: When I make visible the Toolbar of the navcontroller in my view hierarchy, strange black bars appear at the top and bottom of the table view. http://grab.by/8pgz

The app is universal, and on the iPhone simulator (or device) this does not show up, although they use the same UITableViewController subclass.

I cannot even figure out what the extra bars *are*, which makes it even harder to come up with a solution.

They are, however, not navbar / toolbar. They are not section or table view header / footer. It does not merely seem to be a resizing of the table view either, since its background is not black.

The custom table view controller sits inside a UINavigationController, which in turn is inside a UISplitViewController. Pretty standard, as far as I understand.

Like said, they do not show up on the phone - nor do they appear in the popover in portrait orientation.

I'm really out of clues here. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Cheers,

Gregor
Sweden

Update: Problem solved by moving the code for making toolbar visible to -(void)awakeFromNib method instead of -(void)viewDidLoad. Still don't know what went wrong, but now at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with the frame you're trying to use to initialize the tableView.

```
myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width);
```

Try changing the height width variables in code, to reflect your height & width on the iPad.